# Background image in css is not found in Django using scss, webpack

Tags: css, django, webpack, sass

I setup SCSS with webpack in Django. The only problem that I encounter in the setup is that background images in generated css file is not found by Django.

This is the webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,  '../../backend/static/'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../backend/static/'),
    },

    port: 9000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test:/\.scss$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
          ]
      },
      {
          test: /\.vue$/i,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: "vue-loader",
          },
      },
      {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            },
          }
      },
      {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: "html-loader",
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "style-loader"],
      },
      {
          test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
          type: 'asset/inline',
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //   template:"./src/index.html"
    // }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: true,
      __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.vue'],
    alias: {
    },
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/images/"),
      "../node_modules/"
    ],
  },
};
```

This is my Django Settings for static files.

```
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/src/images/'),
]
```

This is the output when retrieving the background image from the css file.

This is the SASS code. The image is correctly outputted in 'static/' folder which is in the Django settings.

What should I do? What is the lacking code in my webpack configuration?

Thank you in advance!

I already tried adding file-loader and url-loader but it didn't work